# Alphabetized file sorting in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

For a while everything was sorted in alphabetical order in Google Drive, but it recently changed to last-used at the top. How do I set it to go back to alphabetical order, so I can find them quickly?

Answer (score 2):

You're under the recent view, you want to switch to the main root folder. See the image below for a demonstration of what I mean.

[image: example image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the "**Sort**" menu (upper right part of the screen)

[image: Google Drive "Sort" menu]

Choose the **Title** option.